# Cycling through array items using a button swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am fairly new to coding, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am creating an app that will (at the press of a button), display the first item of my array on my label, and then if I press the button again, it will display the second item, and then if you press it again, the third, and so on. Right now all I have managed to do is make my app choose a random item from the array, and display it.

Thanks so Much if you could help!

here is my code:

```
let prompts = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]

    @IBOutlet var PromptLbl: UILabel!


    @IBAction func GivePrompt(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let selected = Int (arc4random()) % 8
        PromptLbl.text = (prompts[selected])
    }
```

Comment: what do you want? and what's wrong with your code?

Comment: do you want to show prompt in sequence how about if user tap 8 time then what prompt will come?

Comment: Do you want the elements to be random or in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a variable and keep updating its value by +1 on click of the button.

```
let prompts = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
var currentIndexCount = 0 
@IBOutlet var PromptLbl: UILabel!


@IBAction func GivePrompt(_ sender: UIButton)
{
 if currentIndexCount < prompts.count {
  PromptLbl.text = prompts[currentIndexCount]
  currentIndexCount = currentIndexCount + 1
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I make it so that when I exit the app the index does not reset? The code works though so thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Swift function to get an optional random element. Or if you want to generate an index by yourself, use correct range bounds.

```swift
let prompts = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]

//default collection function
prompts.randomElement()

//random index
let index = Int.random(in: 0..<prompts.count)
prompts[index]
```